# 'too many values to unpack', while iterating over a for loop

Tags: python, loops, iterator, dataset, regression

I'm iterating over multiple regression models in a prediction algorithm. While I iterate over the models from a single list, there is no such error. But when I iterate over 2 lists, one for the models('`classifiers`'), and the other for the name of the models as strings(`'ListOfclassifiers'`), I get an error like: `'ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)'`

```
ListOfclassifiers = ['svm.SVR', 'SGDRegressor', 'BayesianRidge', 'LassoLars', 'ARDRegression',
                     'PassiveAggressiveRegressor',
                     'TheilSenRegressor', 'LinearRegression']
classifiers = [svm.SVR(),
               linear_model.SGDRegressor(),
               linear_model.BayesianRidge(),
               linear_model.LassoLars(),
               linear_model.ARDRegression(),
               linear_model.PassiveAggressiveRegressor(),
               linear_model.TheilSenRegressor(),
               linear_model.LinearRegression()]

for items, types in classifiers, ListOfclassifiers:
    clf = items
    clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
    clf.score(X_test, y_test)
    accuracy = clf.score(X_test, y_test)
    print('The accuracy with', types, 'is:', accuracy)
```

Comment: Should be `for items, types in zip(classifiers, ListOfclassifiers)`

Comment: Works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Merge two arrays with `zip` method:

```
for items, types in zip(classifiers, ListOfclassifiers):
    # todo smth
```